# appcelerator titanium : close facebook view

Tags: facebook, mobile, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I am new to appcelerator titanium, i created a mobile project, tried the following code to connect to facebook:

```
Titanium.Facebook.appid = '[my appid]';
Titanium.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream'];
Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Logged in');
    }
});
Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
    alert('Logged out');
});
// add the button.  Note that it doesn't need a click event or anything.
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({ top: 50, style: 'wide' }));
```

what I failed to do is closing the facebook webview and going back to my application,
can anyone help me on that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good walkthru here [facebook-module-changes-in-titanium-mobile-1-6-0.html](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/02/facebook-module-changes-in-titanium-mobile-1-6-0.html).

I suspect you are not setting your APPID correctly in tiapp.xml

See [Titanium.Facebook-module](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module)